# Android wait for service callback with coroutines

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

I want to connect to a service inside a texture view. The connection can be cut off if the service crashes. For this case a new connection needs to be established.

On every onSurfaceTextureAvailable I check if the service is still alive and running. If not i try to reconnect to the service.

Due that multiple things happen in this view I have to wait till the service is connect and can then continue. I would like to solve it with blocking coroutines like this:

```
suspend fun bindServiceAndWait() = suspendCoroutine<IService> { continuation ->

    Log.i(TAG, "In co-routine")

    val conn = object: ServiceConnection {
        override fun onServiceConnected(name: ComponentName?, service: IBinder?) {
            continuation.resume(IService.Stub.asInterface(service))
        }
        override fun onServiceDisconnected(name: ComponentName?) {
            // don't care here
        }

    }
    // Context is coming from the application it is running
    context.bindService(serviceIntent, conn, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE)
}
```

There problem is that the callback is never executed and so the blocking is never continued.

If I remove the blocking continuation part, everything works fine.

Do you have any idea why this behavior is like this ?

Comment: Is it possible that it's reaching "onServiceDisconnected"? maybe try adding a continuation.resumeWithError or similar.
Additionally ServiceConnection has more methods you might want to override like default void onNullBinding(ComponentName name)